# Pass list of strings from Javascript to asp.net code-behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have problems with javascript in ASP.NET.
I modify a listBox, with add and remove command using javascript.
Now I have to use the data of the list in the code behind. How can I pass this data to the server?  Can I use json?

Here is the code. I can't use hiddenField because of the remove.

```
<asp:listbox ID="SubCat" runat="server" ></asp:listbox>
<input type=button onClick="addOption(SubCat)"; value='Add'> 
<input type=button onClick="removeOptions(SubCat)"; value='Remove Selected'>
<input type=button onClick="removeAllOptions(SubCat)"; value='Remove All'>


<script type="text/javascript">


 function removeAllOptions(selectbox) {
    var i;
    for (i = selectbox.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        selectbox.remove(i);
    }
 } 

 function removeOptions(selectbox) {
    var i;
    for (i = selectbox.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (selectbox.options[i].selected)
           selectbox.remove(i);
    }
 }

 function addOption(selectbox) {
    var txtBox1 = document.getElementById('txForn')
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    var t = txtBox1.value;
    optn.text = t;
    optn.value = t;
    selectbox.options.add(optn);
 }

</ script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use hidden?  You can easily store the ID's of the records of items added or removed from the listbox, and update the server.  Your other options are web service, or stream the data to a handler instead.

Either option, any client-side changes are not persisted, so on every postback, you'd have to reload the ListBox control with the updated data.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a web service and add a method e.g. DeleteSelectedOptions and change the removeOptions function like below:

```
function removeOptions(selectbox) {
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'yourservice.asmx/DeleteSelectedOptions',
       data: "{ids: '" + yourIds + "'}", // yourIds like : "1,6,9,34" 
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (result) {
          //if success, remove option on page
          var i;
          for (i = selectbox.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (selectbox.options[i].selected)
               selectbox.remove(i);
          }
       },
       failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
       }
    });  
  }
```

**Sample WebService Remove.asmx**

```
 [WebMethod]
 public string DeleteSelectedOptions(string ids)
 {
     string[] idsArray = ids.Split(',')
     // your delete codes 
     return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark you would need to make an AJAX request to the server. See my example below.

It utilizes POST in which you could send the fields from your form to your server method. Also POST gives a success function for instance if your method is returning a value and you need to show it on the page, so in this success function you could handle it.

Assuming you have the following method on server-side code behidn file:

```
 public static bool AddNewItem(string name, string surname, int age)
    {


      return true;      
    }

buttons:
{
    "Add": function () {
        var name = $("#<%= txtName.ClientID  %>").val();
        var surname = $("#<%= txtSurname.ClientID %>").val();
        var age = $("#<%= txtAge.ClientID %>").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'MyWebPage.aspx/AddNewItem',
            data: '{"name":"' + name + '", "surname":"' + surname + '", "age":' + age + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.d) {
                    alert("Successfully added new item");                                    
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error! Try again...");
            }
        });
    },
    "Cancel": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
}
```